# how to make listView redirect to website onClick?

Tags: android, string, listview, url, android-studio

I've been trying to make listView redirect user onClick to URL's when clicking on different elements.
Example:
clicking on "apple" would open "stackoverflow.com",
 but clicking on tomato would open "google.com" etc.
Could anyone give me some advice how can I accomplish this, because after 2 days of trying and searching all I've got is a headache..

displayMainMenu.java

```
public class DisplayMainMenu extends Activity
{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_main_menu);
    final String[] food = new String[] {"Apple", "Tomato", "Potato"};


    ListAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, food);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainMenu);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}

class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] values)
    {
        super(context, R.layout.entry, values);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.entry, parent, false);

        String text = getItem(position);

        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listTextView1);
        textView.setText(text);

            return view;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a new class that holds the shown string value (Apple, Tomato, Potato, etc) and also holds the URL that you want to link to.

Then make the ArrayAdapter use that class. The getView function you have already should suffice (when its updated to use the new class).

Then in your activity, use 'setOnItemClickListener' to set a new listener.

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        MyItem clickedItem = () parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        << Insert code to open the link with the URL you can get from 'clickedItem' >>
    }
});
```

That should do it.